# Switching between workspaces from workspace switcher window

Tags: 11.10, keyboard, window

I generally work with mutiple workspaces and use the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>/<kbd>left</kbd> to switch between workspaces.

I like the workspace switcher window in Ubuntu 11.10. Once I get into the workspace switcher window, all the workspaces are shown as tiles. Is there some way to cycle between them using the keyboard and then select any application from the current workspace from the workspace switcher window itself. All I can do now is use my mouse to click on the required workspace and the required application. If I can do this directly from the keyboard, it would be great.

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Arrow keys and Alt-Tab work when you are in workspace switcher mode.

So, hit Super-S to open the workspace switcher, then use arrow keys to navigate to the workspace you want, Alt-Tab until the application you want is at the front, and then hit Enter to maximize that workspace.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my arrow keys or alt+tab or ctrl+tab are not working when I am in the workspace switcher window. I run a wubi install of ubuntu 11.10. Should I fiddle with any of the Compiz settings to get this working?